# Detect empty line (contain only space) in perl

Tags: regex, perl

my program read a file, and i don't want to treat empty line

```
while (<FICC>) {
my $ligne=$_;
if ($ligne =~ /^\s*$/){}else{
print " $ligne\n";}
```

but this code also print empty line

the file that i test with contain:

```
Ms. Ruth Dreifuss Dreifuss Federal Councillor Federal ruth
     
sir christopher warren US Secretary of state secretary of state
     
external economic case federal economic affair conference the Federal Office case
     
US bill clinton bill clinton Mr. Bush
     
Nestle food cs holding swiss Swiss Performance Index Performance
```

Comment: Can you post a dump of the "empty line"? `print join ' ', map ord, split //, $ligne`.

Comment: the program print 10

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because of using the `\n` within your code. Just remove that `\n` from your code and it should be fine.

Usually people do `chomp` after reading a line from a file to remove the end of line character.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to write that is probably to invert the logic and only print lines that contain non-whitespace characters.

```
while (<FICC>) {
  my $ligne = $_;
  if ($ligne =~ /\S/) {
    print " $ligne"; # No need for linefeed here as $ligne already has one
  }
}
```

**Update:** Demo using your sample data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my $ligne = $_;

  if ($ligne =~ /\S/) {
    print " $ligne";
  }
}

__END__
Ms. Ruth Dreifuss Dreifuss Federal Councillor Federal ruth

sir christopher warren US Secretary of state secretary of state

external economic case federal economic affair conference the Federal Office case

US bill clinton bill clinton Mr. Bush

Nestle food cs holding swiss Swiss Performance Index Performance
```

Output:

```
 Ms. Ruth Dreifuss Dreifuss Federal Councillor Federal ruth
 sir christopher warren US Secretary of state secretary of state
 external economic case federal economic affair conference the Federal Office case
 US bill clinton bill clinton Mr. Bush
 Nestle food cs holding swiss Swiss Performance Index Performance
```

Which seems correct to me.

Comment: I think the OP's issue is that they are printing `"$ligne\n"` without chomping the original newline, so the output is double-spaced

Comment: the problem is if i add 'else{ print "ligne"}' this print empty line, so it detect the empty line but the else didn't do nothing

Comment: See my update. If you want any more help, you're going to have to be a lot clearer about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is also that you're adding a new line, to the end of your string which already has a newline in it "$ligne\n", so use **chomp** as below

I think the nicer way of doing this is with **next** (skip to next loop iteration) as it removes some brackets from your code:

```
while (<FICC>) {
    my $ligne=chomp $_;
    next if $ligne =~ /^\s*$/;
    print " $ligne\n";
}
```